# how can i implement a click listener for vaadin 23 forgot password button

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin, forgot-password

I need to implement a click listener for a LoginI18n loginView forgot password button. Can any one help me out?

I have tried looking for a ForgotPasswordEvent method in the AbstractLogin class but failed to use it.

Answer (score 5):

You where looking in the wrong place.  The `LoginI18n` only holds text
for localization.  You need
[`addForgotPasswordListener`](https://origin.vaadin.com/api/platform/current/com/vaadin/flow/component/login/AbstractLogin.html#addForgotPasswordListener(com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventListener))
on your login form.